# Can't directly use Pandas Nullable Int types for Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, nullable

TL;DR: When I try to set the index to a [Pandas Nullable Integer type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html), it gets stored as the generic `object` type instead.

If I've got a dataframe setup like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'A': [1, 2, None, 100, 200],
    'B': [7, None, 77, None, 777],
    },
    dtype='Int64'  # pandas Nullalbe Int type
)
df.dtypes

Out[1]:
X    Int64
A    Int64
B    Int64
dtype: object
```

By default, the index is 0 to 4 and type `int64`:

```py
In [2]: df.index.dtype, df.index.inferred_type, df.index.is_numeric()
Out[2]: (dtype('int64'), 'integer', True)
```

**But when I set one of those `Int64` columns ('X') to be the index, the index's dtype is `object`; even though it's inferred as numeric:**

```py
In [3]: df.set_index('X', drop=False, inplace=True)
   ...: df.index.dtype, df.index.inferred_type, df.index.is_numeric()
Out[3]: (dtype('O'), 'integer', True)
```

If I convert the column to a standard type (`np.int`) and set it as the index, then it works as per the normal/old(?) way:

```py
In [4]: df['X'] = df['X'].astype('int64')  # lowercase 'i'
   ...: df.set_index('X', drop=False, inplace=True)
   ...: df.index.dtype, df.index.inferred_type, df.index.is_numeric()
Out[4]: (dtype('int64'), 'integer', True)
```

I'm also not able to cast the index to a Nullable Int type:

```py
In [5]: df.index.astype('Int64')
Out[5]: Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='object', name='X')
```

Works fine for Series

```py
In [6]: pd.Series(df['X'].astype('Int64')).dtype
Out[6]: Int64Dtype()
```

...but not if I try to assign it to the index.

```py
In [7]: df.index = pd.Series(df['X'].astype('Int64'))
   ...: df.index
Out[7]: Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='object', name='X')
```

If I try to the values then I get a deprecation warning; but still returns `int64` (lowercase 'i' / numpy).

```py
In [10]: df.index.values.astype('Int64')
<ipython-input-10-6e18e0684d5a>:1: DeprecationWarning: Numeric-style type codes are deprecated and will result in an error in the future.
  df.index.values.astype('Int64')
Out[10]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64)
```

Is this a bug/limitation of the new dtypes? If so, it's not specifically mentioned in the linked docs.

Comment: Actually they are not stored as `object`,  when you typed `df.types` it gives you in the output a pandas.Series of type object but it doesn't mean that your columns are of type object.

Comment: Do you mean 'container types' vs 'data types' in the container? If so, the container type for the columns accepts that it's `Int64` but not for the index. And when the index is `int64` (lowercase 'i'), it shows that for the container. Usually, `object` is when it's a generic python type (non-pandas, non-numpy) type or a container with mixed types. And it shouldn't be a mixed type since the source is not of mixed types.

Comment: It is generally not advisable to have NaNs in your index. Can you explain a little about your use case, perhaps it makes sense to fill the NaNs or drop rows, or just use a normal integer index.

Comment: @cs95 The column I'm setting as the index (or trying to) has no Null values. It's the Primary Key of a table from someone else's DB extract. I could happily ignore the auto-index in my use-case and have 'X' only as a column. But I'm curious - `Int64` types for the index become `object` but `int64` is allowed. Does that mean `int64` would be an "upgrade" of sorts that fits the data (being a non-nullable int type)? How could I then have 'X' as the index without it becoming `object`? The only was I see how is one of the methods above: `df.set_index(df['X'].astype('int64'), ...)`.

Comment: I think this just means that pandas extension types are not yet supported in index objects - only numpy types.

Comment: Extension types in general (including nullable types) are indeed not yet supported as Index at the moment, see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39133 for a tracking issue.